How to solve the Conv3d function error: expected input to have 1 channels, but got 128 channels instead?
When the program runs to the function "Depthwise SeparateConv", an error message will be reported as follows.
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [1, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input [8, 128, 128, 128, 1] to have 1 channel, but got 128 channels installed.

The following is my code based on Python 3.9.19, which is used to distinguish whether the input MRI image is a normal person or a patient with Alzheimer's disease.
import os

os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0'
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"

import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

from torch.nn import BCEWithLogitsLoss
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.optim import Adam


def preprocess_data(file_path):
    try:
        img = nib.load(file_path)
        img_data = img.get_fdata(dtype=np.float64)
        zoom_shape = (128, 128, 128, 1)
        zoom_factors = (zoom_shape[0] / img_data.shape[0],
                        zoom_shape[1] / img_data.shape[1],
                        zoom_shape[2] / img_data.shape[2],
                        1)
        resampled_data = ndimage.zoom(img_data, zoom_factors, order=1, mode='grid-constant')
        return resampled_data
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error {file_path}: {e}")
        return None


def load_data(datadir):
    alzheimer_dir = os.path.join(datadir, 'alzheimer') 
    normal_dir = os.path.join(datadir, 'normal')  
    x0 = []
    y0 = []
    for filename in os.listdir(alzheimer_dir):
        if filename.endswith('.nii'):
            file_path = os.path.join(alzheimer_dir, filename)
            try:
                img_data = preprocess_data(file_path)
                x0.append(img_data)
                y0.append(1)  
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"AD error {file_path}: {e}")

    for filename in os.listdir(normal_dir):
        if filename.endswith('.nii'):
            file_path = os.path.join(normal_dir, filename)
            try:
                img_data = preprocess_data(file_path)
                x0.append(img_data)
                y0.append(0) 
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"normal error {file_path}: {e}")
    # x0 = torch.tensor(x0, dtype=torch.float64)
    x0 = torch.tensor(np.array(x0), dtype=torch.float64)
    y0 = torch.tensor(y0, dtype=torch.long)
    return x0, y0


class EarlyStopping:
    def __init__(self, save_path='./savemodel2/', patience=7, verbose=False,
                 delta=0):
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.patience = patience
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.counter = 0
        self.best_score = None
        self.early_stop = False
        self.val_loss_min = np.Inf
        self.delta = delta

    def __call__(self, val_loss, model):

        score = -val_loss

        if self.best_score is None:
            self.best_score = score
            self.save_checkpoint(val_loss, model)
        elif score < self.best_score + self.delta:
            self.counter += 1
            print(f'EarlyStopping counter: {self.counter} out of {self.patience}')
            if self.counter >= self.patience:
                self.early_stop = True
        else:
            self.best_score = score
            self.save_checkpoint(val_loss, model)
            self.counter = 0

    def save_checkpoint(self, val_loss, model):
        if self.verbose:
            print(f'Validation loss decreased ({self.val_loss_min:.6f} --> {val_loss:.6f}).  Saving model ...')
        path = os.path.join(self.save_path, 'best_network.pth')
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), path)  
        self.val_loss_min = val_loss


class DepthwiseSeparableConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, bias=False):
        super(DepthwiseSeparableConv, self).__init__()
        self.depthwise = nn.Conv3d(input_channels, input_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=0,groups=1, bias=bias)
        self.pointwise = nn.Conv3d(input_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=bias)
        self.depthwise.weight.data = self.depthwise.weight.data.type(torch.float64)
        self.pointwise.weight.data = self.pointwise.weight.data.type(torch.float64)
        if bias:
            self.depthwise.bias.data = self.depthwise.bias.data.type(torch.float64)
            self.pointwise.bias.data = self.pointwise.bias.data.type(torch.float64)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.depthwise(x)
        out = self.pointwise(out)
        return out


def residual_block(x0, out_channels, input_channels):
    conv1 = DepthwiseSeparableConv(input_channels, out_channels)
    conv2 = DepthwiseSeparableConv(out_channels, out_channels)
    relu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.01)

    if input_channels != out_channels:
        residual = nn.Conv3d(input_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3)(x0)
    else:
        residual = x0

    out = conv1(x0)
    out = relu(out)
    out = conv2(out)
    out += residual
    out = relu(out)
    return out


def build_model(input_shape):
    class Model(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_shape0):
            super(Model, self).__init__()
            input_channels = input_shape0[-1]
            self.depthwise_sep_conv = DepthwiseSeparableConv(input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3)
            self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm3d(input_channels)
            self.res_block1 = lambda x: residual_block(x, 32, input_channels)
            self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2))
            self.res_block2 = lambda x: residual_block(x, 64, 32)
            self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2))
            self.res_block3 = lambda x: residual_block(x, 128, 64)
            self.maxpool3 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2))
            self.global_avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d((8, 8, 8))

            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 8 * 8 * 8, 256)
            self.leaky_relu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
            self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.6)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 1)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.depthwise_sep_conv(x)
            x = x.type(torch.float32)
            x = self.batch_norm(x)
            x = self.res_block1(x)
            x = self.maxpool1(x)
            x = self.res_block2(x)
            x = self.maxpool2(x)
            x = self.res_block3(x)
            x = self.maxpool3(x)
            x = self.global_avg_pool(x)
            x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
            x = self.fc1(x)
            x = self.leaky_relu(x)
            x = self.dropout(x)
            x = self.fc2(x)
            return x

    model = Model(input_shape)
    return model


def compile_and_train_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val):
    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    criterion = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=7, verbose=True, delta=0.5,
                                   save_path='./savemodel/')

    batch_size = 8
    epochs = 80
    loss = 0

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        for i in range(0, len(x_train), batch_size):
            x_batch = x_train[i:i + batch_size]
            y_batch = y_train[i:i + batch_size]
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(x_batch)
            loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        model.eval()
        val_loss = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for i in range(0, len(x_val), batch_size):
                x_batch = x_val[i:i + batch_size]
                y_batch = y_val[i:i + batch_size]
                outputs = model(x_batch)
                val_loss += criterion(outputs, y_batch).item()

        val_loss /= (len(x_val) / batch_size)

        early_stopping(val_loss, model)
        if early_stopping.early_stop:
            print("early-stopping")
            break

        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {loss.item()}, Val Loss: {val_loss}')
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(early_stopping.save_path, 'best_network.pth')))


def evaluate_model(model, x_test, y_test):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        y_pred = model(x_test)
        y_pred_binary = (y_pred > 0.5).type(torch.int) 

    correct = (torch.tensor(y_pred_binary == y_test)).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    accuracy = float(correct) / len(y_test)
    # accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)[1]

    y_pred_binary = y_pred_binary.numpy()
    y_test = y_test.numpy() 

    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred_binary)
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred_binary)
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred_binary)
    auc_roc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred.numpy())

    print(f'Test accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')
    print(f'Precision: {precision:.4f}')
    print(f'recall: {recall:.4f}')
    print(f'F1 score: {f1:.4f}')
    print(f'AUC-ROC: {auc_roc:.4f}')


def main():
    data_dir = 'C:/3/'
    x, y = load_data(data_dir)
    x_train, x_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=int(0.6 * len(x)), random_state=36)
    x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_temp, y_temp, test_size=0.2, random_state=36)

    input_shape = torch.Tensor(128, 128, 128, 1)
    model = build_model(input_shape)
    compile_and_train_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)
    evaluate_model(model, x_test, y_test)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The error tracing information is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\4.py", line 334, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\4.py", line 329, in main
    compile_and_train_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\4.py", line 260, in compile_and_train_model
    outputs = model(x_batch)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\4.py", line 206, in forward
    x = self.depthwise_sep_conv(x)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\4.py", line 136, in forward
    out = self.depthwise(x)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 610, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 605, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv3d(
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [1, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[8, 128, 128, 128, 1] to have 1 channels, but got 128 channels instead

At the beginning, the error message reported by Pycharm was (RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous). I thought it might be due to an issue with "input_channels=input_shape0 [-1]" in the build_model function, so I forcibly specified "input_channels=1". However, this message was not reported again, which caused this new problem.
I checked the x_train shape (print (x_train. shape)) and the output is tensor. torch Size (\[178, 128, 128, 128, 1\]).
It seems that I expected the input shape to be [batch_size, depth, height, width, channels], but when I actually used it, it became [batch_size, channels, depth, height, width]. I don't know why.
I searched for similar questions from other users, and one of the answers suggested that I modify the Depthwise SeparateConv function.
def forward(self, x):
x = x.permute(0, 4, 1, 2, 3)
out = self.depthwise(x)
out = self.pointwise(out)
return out

This does work, but I'm not sure if it caused other issues, such as when I ran with modified code and the compiler reported an error message.
File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\4.py", line 209, in forward
    x = self.batch_norm(x)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py", line 175, in forward
    return F.batch_norm(
  File "C:\Users\wangh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2509, in batch_norm
    return torch.batch_norm(
RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 32 elements not 1

self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm3d(input_channels) didn't read the input channel in real time, so I had to change it to self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm3d(num_features=32). I'm not sure if this will cause problems with the model later on.
Anyway, after I made the above modifications, the code ran until x = self.res_block1(x). Another problem has arisen, RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[8, 32, 126, 126, 126] to have 1 channels, but got 32 channels instead.
The same problem as at the beginning appeared, which made me very frustrated. I don't understand why. In my eyes, everything seems to become chaotic in the code.
If someone could help me, I would be extremely grateful!
